# Editing Default HTML Template with Pencil Mockup Tool?

Tags: mockups, mockup-tool, evolus-pencil

I'm trying to edit the default HTML template so that I can comment out the document header and time stamp, but I am having trouble trying to locate the template. I followed an article, but it didn't really help, considering how the directory structure is completely different to the one I have.

https://kalpeshshirodker.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/evolus-pencil-how-to-removemodify-headers-while-printing-a-document-to-pdf-printer/

Any ideas as to where this template might be in the latest version of pencil?

Comment: Is it correct that you want to print the default HTML template without the header and timestamp?

Comment: Yes. Is it still possible? Because if so, then I might try out pencil again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest version of Pencil which is 3.x, you have 2 print options for hiding title and header/footer

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! If I decide to give Pencil another go, then I won't have to worry about the document header and time stamp. It was annoying I couldn't get rid of it, but I'm glad they implemented an option.

Comment: @userrandomuser The application is under active development. Head over to its GitHub repository and file an issue whenever you want to request a feature or report a bug.

Comment: @userrandomuser Accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: OK and I think your answer works for me. Plus, the question was asked a while ago so yeah I'll accept your answer. Thanks.